# Using VBA to get a threshold value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column A and a column B. In column A, I have (starting in A2) values that go from 1-150 (so ending in A151)

In column B, I have values. I want to get the first value that is above the value in cell Z2 and write out the corresponing value in the A column in cell B153 for column B. Last part is tricky. I only want to write this value if the following 4 values are also above the value in Z2. Is this possible to d?

If this is, I also have the same thing in columns C-Y[image]

Better explanation:

I want to loop through columns B-Y
Inner loop from cells 2-151.

If B2>Z2 but also next 4 sequential cells (B3-B6)>Z2, then copy A2 to B153 and move to next column.
If B2 > Z2 but next 4 are not all > Z2, repeat process with B3.
If B2 < Z2, move to B3.

If none is true copy N/A to B153

Can this be done?

My first attempt:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$151,SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(1,--(B$2:B$151>$Z$2),0)),1)
```

This takes the first value though. I'm trying to think of a clever way to take the first value only if the second value also meets criteria. From there I'm sure I can expand to 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc.

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please post your attempted solution

Comment: @Barranka I posted what I have tried. Simple code in another cell in the Worksheet

Comment: Another way to think about it with VBA is to loop through each column. Start with B2. If B2-B6 are all greater than Z2, return A2. If not, go to B3 and repeat. Once value is found, post in B153 and move to next column, stopping at column Y. I can think of how it could be done, just struggling writing anything that works.

Comment: If you post some screenshots of the data layout and expected results, I will help you. I am having trouble understanding what the data looks like and what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: @user1274820 Ok I posted an example. The highlighted cells are for visual help. See how column B, there are 2 highlighted but the ones after are not highlighted? But cell the value of 43 corresponds with the first value in column A that also have the next 4 values are also greater than Z2. does this make any sense?

Comment: I would like to post 43 in cell B153 and do the same analysis for the other columns too. I have 100s of these sheets and manually will take a long time, and I'm sure to make mistakes. If there is a VBA script that could loop through each column and each cell in each column, see if the B2>Z2. If it is, see if B3-B6 are also greater. If not, skip to B3 and repeat. Once satisified, post corresponding value in A to B153

Comment: I added better explanation. @user1274820 any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub OutputEnergy()    
'y = Columns to check: 2-25
'x = Rows to check: 2-152
'z = check the next 4 cells
Dim x, y, z, check
'Clear the range where we store the #N/A or Energy Outputs
Range("B153:Y153") = vbNullString
For y = 2 To 25
    For x = 2 To 152
        If Cells(x, y) > Range("Z2") Then  'If value is greater than Z2
            check = True                   'Let's check the next 4
            For z = 1 To 4                 'If any of them fail
                If Cells(x + z, y) < Range("Z2") Then
                    check = False          'The check fails
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next z
            If check = True Then            'If the check doesn't fail
                Cells(153, y) = Cells(x, 1) 'Set cell 153 to the energy level
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next x                                   'If no energy level was set - #N/A
    If Cells(153, y) = vbNullString Then Cells(153, y) = "#N/A"
Next y
End Sub
```

**Edit: As a function:**

Function Usage:

`=OutputEnergy(Range, Threshold, [Number of cells to check], [Using Headers?])`

Basically, give it the range to check, give it a threshold.

The number of cells to check afterwards is 4 by default.

To get the "Energy" it gets the row number (If using headers, it subtracts 1)

```
Function OutputEnergy(TheRange As Range, Threshold As Variant, Optional NextCells As Integer = 4, Optional OffsetForHeader As Boolean = True) As Variant    
Dim c, x, check
For Each c In TheRange
    If c.Value > Threshold Then
        check = True
        For x = 1 To NextCells
            If c.Offset(x, 0) < Threshold Then
                check = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
        If check = True Then
            OutputEnergy = IIf(OffsetForHeader, c.Row - 1, c.Row)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
Next c
OutputEnergy = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

**Edit again - to output to all sheets:**

OutputEnergyToSheet accepts a sheet as a parameter:

```
Sub OutputEnergyToSheet(TheSheet As String)
'y = Columns to check: 2-25
'x = Rows to check: 2-152
'z = check the next 4 cells
Dim x, y, z, check
'Clear the range where we store the #N/A or Energy Outputs
With Sheets(TheSheet)
    .Range("B153:Y153") = vbNullString
    For y = 2 To 25
        For x = 2 To 152
            If .Cells(x, y) > .Range("Z2") Then  'If value is greater than Z2
                check = True                   'Let's check the next 4
                For z = 1 To 5                 'If any of them fail
                    If .Cells(x + z, y) < .Range("Z2") Then
                        check = False          'The check fails
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next z
                If check = True Then                    'If the check doesn't fail
                    .Cells(153, y) = Int(.Cells(x, 1))  'Set cell 153 to the energy level
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next x                                   'If no energy level was set - #N/A
        If .Cells(153, y) = vbNullString Then .Cells(153, y) = "#N/A"
    Next y
End With
End Sub
```

OutputEnergyToAllSheets loops through each sheet and calls the new sub:

```
Sub OutputEnergyToAllSheets()
Dim w
For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not InStr(w.Name, "Total") > 0 And Not InStr(w.Name, "eV") > 0 Then
        OutputEnergyToSheet w.Name
    End If
Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: It should work by changing that value. The only issue with that loop is when you hit the bottom and it starts running into blank cells. I'm not sure how you want to handle those cases. My guess is it should fail which I believe it will.

Comment: Is there a way for this to loop through all worksheets except for those with a "Total" or "eV"  somewhere in the name?

Comment: I never specified sheets so you should be able to select each sheet and run the macro again - if the ranges need to be modified however, it will be a little trickier. It can be rewritten to use last row and various ranges. If the layouts are identical, you can use `For Each w in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets If Not InStr(w.Name,"Total") > 0 and Not InStr(w.Name, "eV") > 0 Then n.Select Call OutputEnergy Next w`

Comment: I tried copying but I think the format may be messed up?

Comment: Originally he said it needed to return values to all columns, so I didn't write it as a function. Yes, it could be written as a function to return one value that could then be dragged across the bottom of his data.

Comment: I just did that, but it's untested.

Comment: Also, it is oututting the numbers not as numbers. I am having to manually convert to numbers on each sheet. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Jack, you can use the `NumberFormat` property to change the type. `Cells(153, y) = Cells(x, 1) 'Set cell 153 to the energy level` `Cells(153, y).NumberFormat = "General"` or something like that. I'm not quite sure what else it would be formatting them as, however.

Comment: Its already storing them as general, but I cant take average because it does not recognize as a number

Comment: Jack, it's setting the value to the value you have in the "Energy" field. You can try adding `Int()` - Change the line to:  `Cells(153, y) = Int(Cells(x, 1)) 'Set cell 153 to the energy level`

Comment: Cool! Im still having the issue of looping through the worksheets, I Tried what you said but it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: I think the problem is I can loop it, but it still only pastes values in current ws.

Comment: Hi Jack, I edited the answer with new code to that accepts a sheet name as a parameter and a new sub that will loop through sheets not containing Total or eV. You should be able to paste the new code into your module and run `OutputEnergyToAllSheets`.

Comment: @user1274820 Is there an easy way to loop through threshold choices? Like for threshold 0, post that in 153, for 1, post that in 154 up to threshold 10?

Comment: Yes, you can wrap it in another loop or you can try using the function I wrote. You would want to replace the `.Range("Z2")` with a value from the loops and you would want to offset the output by the new loop variable as well. So, "easy" is kind of open to interpretation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80935/discussion-between-jack-and-user1274820).

Comment: I tried offsetting, I seems to work ok, but I have to work backwards, it deletes the previous row

Answer (score 2):

Your current formula might work for the single value case but I think it would be a littly clumsy to try to scale up. A couple quick ways to accomplish this via formula are:

```
=MIN(IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B"&ROW(2:147)&":B"&ROW(6:151)),">"&Z2)=5,$A2:$A147,1E9))
```

And:

```
=MIN(IF((B2:B147>Z2)*(B3:B148>Z2)*(B4:B149>Z2)*(B5:B150>Z2)*(B6:B151>Z2),$A2:$A147,1E9))
```

Personally I think the latter is easier to read and drag through the spreadsheet (though the former could be modified to drag just as easily). The latter also avoids the volatile `INDIRECT` function. The first function takes 5 cell ranges at a time and counts the number of cells that match the criteria. If our count is 5, we have a match. This method is preferred if you are looking for larger sets of matches. The second formula just steps through the range checking basically r through r+4 where r is the current row. Both are array formulas that should be entered with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to solve this, but in my opinion you need a nested loop in a user-defined function.

We can...

```
function get_Energy_Row(cellSearch as Range, staticValue as Single)

  Dim cell1 as Single

  get_Energy_Row = "N/A"

  j = 1 
  col = cellSearch.Columns.Count

  Do
      cell1 = cellSearch(j, col) 

      If cell1 <= staticValue Then
          'do nothing, function already set to "N/A"
      Else

          For i = 1 to 4
              If cellSearch(i + j, col) > staticValue Then
                  get_Energy_Row = cellSearch(j,1)
              Else
                  'do nothing, function already set to "N/A"
              End If
          Next i
      End If

      j = j + 1

  Loop Until j >= cellSearch.Rows.Count - 3 Or get_Energy_Row <> "N/A"

End Function
```

Then call your UDF in cell `C153` like this:

`=get_Energy_Row($A2:B151,$Z$2)`, where you encompass the first column.

Note the dollar signs, this will ensure that your static check will always be Z2

The logic is that I default the cell to "N/A" until it finds a criteria that overwrites "N/A", in which case the loop is broken.

Comment: Yeah I just ran it - I think there must be at least one bug.

Comment: Fixed it, for what it's worth.