# Looping through numbers to create a large table

Tags: vba, excel, indexing

I have a code that works, but I want to add some more functionality to it. It currently does what it is supposed to do, and has sped up some processes, but now I think it can be sped up even more. I am using the solution that I marked as answered here: [Using VBA to get a threshold value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922657/using-vba-to-get-a-threshold-value)

But

I have this code:

```
Sub OutputEnergyToAllSheets()
Dim w
For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not InStr(w.Name, "Total") > 0 And Not InStr(w.Name, "eV") Then
        OutputEnergyToSheet w.Name
    End If
Next w
End Sub

Sub OutputEnergyToSheet(TheSheet As String)
'y = Columns to check: 2-25
'x = Rows to check: 2-152
'z = check the next 4 cells
Dim x, y, z, check
'Clear the range where we store the #N/A or Energy Outputs
With Sheets(TheSheet)
    .Range("B153:Y153") = vbNullString
    For y = 2 To 25
        For x = 2 To 152
            If .Cells(x, y) > .Range("Z2") Then  'If value is greater than Z2
                check = True                   'Let's check the next 4
                For z = 1 To 30                'If any of them fail
                    If .Cells(x + z, y) < .Range("Z2") Then
                        check = False          'The check fails
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next z
                If check = True Then                    'If the check doesn't fail
                    .Cells(153, y) = Int(.Cells(x, 1))  'Set cell 153 to the energy level
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next x                                   'If no energy level was set - #N/A
        If .Cells(153, y) = vbNullString Then .Cells(153, y) = ""
    Next y
End With
End Sub
```

But the line that says:

```
for z = 1 to 30
```

I am having to change from 0 to 100 in increments of 1. It outputs these values where it should on all worksheets and then I go to the sub and increase value and repeat. The values are output in each worksheet except a few in row 153. Is there a way to have 0 be in row 153, 1 be in 154, 2 in 155, etc up to 100? I understand if this is not possible, but it would me a TON of time, because I have to go through this process for many workbooks. If this can be done it will save me several monotonous hours of busy-work. Anyways, thanks for reading.

Comment: The logic you are shooting for is not exactly clear.  Are you trying to output `0,1,2,...` to rows `153,154,155,...`?  If so, you can use the `row number - 153` to translate.  If that's not the goal, please add additional detail (and maybe a picture) to your question.  if not a picture, then improvement on the input/output relationship would help.

Comment: @Byron That is the goal. I want to loop through all worksheets like I have, starting at 0, put the results in row 153 of each worksheet. Then I want to loop through with z=1 to 1 and paste those results in row 154 of each worksheet. The code works, I just need it to be edited with another loop I think starting at row 153 and going to like row 252 or something

Comment: @Bryon Do you know whether this can be done? I only ask because if not, I should go ahead and start the monotonous busy-work.

Comment: Nearly anything can be done, but it is still not clear what exactly you are trying to do.  You need to provide a picture or some sample output or a clearer description of exactly what you expect to happen.

Comment: @Byron I guess I don't understand how to describe it. Currently the code loops through all worksheets and outputs the results in line 153. I was changing the z loop and running each time. I would do this 100 times to go from 0 to 99 in z-loop. Each time the results are posted in row 153 of each worksheet. I don't want to have to do each increment manually. I want the loop to first look at z from 1 to 0, and then post those in row 153, then loop at z from 1 to 1, then post those in row 154. I'm sorry,  I just want each result posted in succession, rather than overwriting the same row each time.

Comment: So does the 0 to 100 represent 1 to 101 consecutive values greater than the threshold?? Are you saying B153 shows the first row id greater than threshold and B154 shows first set of two greater values and B155 tells us where to find the first set of 3 greater values??

Comment: If so, I can write an answer showing how to do it with the current code but also how to rewrite this code mostly from scratch (as you said "I think it can be sped up") since neither of the answers on the original question is particularly efficient. But I probably won't have time until later tonight. The short answer is that everybody seems to be overthinking this problem. I think I know what you are looking for mainly because I already assessed your situation before posting a formula answer on the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this first code block, I tried to stay with the general structure of the code in your question. I could have for example swapped out the innermost two `For` loops for a single `While` loop. That would be more efficient but requires a significant logic change. I did make some changes though. I set everything to "N/A" at the beginning instead of the end and I added a condition to the last `If` statement. To implement your new functionality of checking for variable numbers of consecutive cells, I included another `For` loop with counter `k` around the `For` loop with counter `z` and made the end point of `z` dependent on `k`. We print out to row `152 + k`.

```
Sub OutputEnergyToSheet(TheSheet As String)
    'y = Columns to check: 2-25
    'x = Rows to check: 2-152
    'k = number of matches in a row to find
    'z = check the next (k - 1) cells
    Dim x, y, z, check, k
    'Clear the range where we store the N/A or Energy Outputs
    With Sheets(TheSheet)
        .Range("B153:Y252") = "N/A"
        For y = 2 To 25
            For x = 2 To 151
                If .Cells(x, y) > .Range("Z2") Then  'If value is greater than Z2
                    For k = 1 To 100
                        check = True                   'Let's check the next k - 1
                        For z = 1 To k - 1             'If any of them fail
                            If .Cells(x + z, y) <= .Range("Z2") Then
                                check = False          'The check fails
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next z
                        If check = True And .Cells(152 + k, y) = "N/A" Then
                            .Cells(152 + k, y) = Int(.Cells(x, 1))
                        End If
                    Next k
                End If
            Next x
        Next y
    End With
End Sub
```

Before I did all this, I threw together my own method which is cleaner and runs **much** faster. The code below steps down the rows and maintains a running count of how many consecutive matches it has found. It eliminates a lot of checks because it only checks any given cell once. Down to 2 total loops! The code above was checking a cell many times over in the inner loops. The below code could probably be better by maintaining the values in an array (read/write in Excel is slow) and/or maintaining a counter of the maximum length I have already achieved for the current column. I stored most of my numbers as variables that can be easily and confidently modified.

```
Sub EfficientEnergy(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, ctr As Integer
    Dim compVal As Double
    Dim maxRow As Integer, maxCol As Integer, maxConsecutive As Integer
    maxRow = 151
    maxCol = 25
    maxConsecutive = 100
    compVal = ws.Cells(2, 26).Value
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(maxRow + 2, 2), ws.Cells(maxRow + maxConsecutive + 1, maxCol)).Value = "N/A"
    For c = 2 To maxCol
        ctr = 0
        For r = 2 To maxRow
            If ws.Cells(r, c).Value > compVal Then
                ctr = ctr + 1
                If ws.Cells(maxRow + 1 + ctr, c).Value = "N/A" Then
                   ws.Cells(maxRow + 1 + ctr, c).Value = ws.Cells(r - ctr + 1, 1).Value
                End If
            Else
                ctr = 0
            End If
        Next r
    Next c
End Sub
```

The code I am using to call these methods in my testing is (just comment out whichever one you aren't using):

```
Public Sub GetConsecutiveVals()
    'OutputEnergyToSheet ("Sheet1")
    Call EfficientEnergy(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"))
End Sub
```

Or to run on every worksheet in active workbook (untested):

```
Public Sub GetConsecutiveVals()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'OutputEnergyToSheet (ws.Name)
        Call EfficientEnergy(ws)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Place all your code in a module in a workbook. Open your workbook with data in Sheet1 (or change the code above to your sheet name). Hit Alt + F8 and then run the GetConsecutiveVals routine. If you don't see that method in the dialog window, make sure the workbook with the code and the workbook with your data are in the same Excel application window

Comment: Can you explain to me how to run this?? Whenever I try, it just asks me to create a new macro, and it try add a sun and end sub at the bottom. Is there a certain way I need to execute this?

Comment: @Jack I added some details on how to run it. I provided the Sub and End Sub lines. Don't place this between any other Sub line and its corresponding End Sub line. Does my added information answer your questions?

Comment: @Jack Also make sure you don't have 2 subs with the same name (like my `OutputEnergyToSheet` and the one from your question).

Comment: It works really well! May I ask just two more things? Instead of N/A when it does not work, could it just be a blank cell? I tried changing "N/A" to "" but then it gave me N/A for everything. Also, in my original code, you can see I ran it for only certain worksheets. Could that be done here too? I don't want to apply code to all sheets. I had it so it would do it to all but certain ones that had something specific in their name. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Jack 1) N/A occurs twice in my code. Make sure you replace it with "" in both places. 2) Yes. You can use the same calling code you used earlier (OutputEnergyToAllSheets) instead of the GetConsecutiveVals function I provided. Just change `Dim w` to `Dim w As Worksheet` and `OutputEnergyToSheet w.Name` to `EfficientEnergy w`.

Comment: Jack, did you ever get this working? Did you try using the worksheet function I wrote? I added the parameter so you could change the number of consecutive cells checked although that wasn't part of your original question.

Comment: I have never used functions before.. Sorry for my inexperience, I was not sure how to get it running

Answer (score 0):

@jack This is how i read this code. Check all cells from Column 2 - 25, Rows 2 - 152, if one of them is greater than Z2, Enter Zloop, Begin checking the next 30 rows, to see if any of those are smaller. if so do nothing, if one is, in cell 153,y = Column 1 same row, go to next column ..question: Why have Z only check 30? why not have it check the remaining 152 ...z= 1 to 152 - x ?

in any case i think this is what you want to do, create another variable say

```
DIM Result As Integer

Result = 153

''then below
If check = True Then                    'If the check doesn't fail
 ''.Cells(153, y) = Int(.Cells(x, 1))  'Set cell 153 to the energy level
 .Cells(Result, y) = Int(.Cells(x, 1))  'Set cell 153 to the energy level
Result = Result + 1
EXIT FOR
```

Comment: Sorry this does not work. You are mistaken about the loop. It does not go from z=1 to z=30. I have to change it each time. First time I run it as z=1 to 0. then I run again as z=1 to 1 up to 100 or something. The code you gave gives a diagnol line downwards with the same results from z=1 to whatever I chose. Remember the z is not looping from 1 to 30, that loop is not really a loop. It is a logic thing it has to do. I want it loop but the way it is currently written, it does not loop

Answer (score 0):

Why use three loops when one would do?

```
Sub OutputEnergyToAllSheets()
    Dim w as worksheet
    For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not InStr(1, w.Name, "Total") > 0 And Not InStr(1, w.Name, "eV") Then
            OutputEnergyToSheet w.Name
        End If
    Next w
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub OutputEnergyToSheet(TheSheet As String)
    Dim check as Boolean
    Dim rng as Range
    Dim c
    Dim ELevel as integer
    'Clear the range where we store the #N/A or Energy Outputs
    With Sheets(TheSheet)
        ' set all cells in row 153 = 0
        .Range("B153:Y153").value = 0 
        ELevel = .cells(2,26)
        ' Your range
        set rng = .Range(.Cells(2,2), .cells(25, 153))

        ' Loop through all cells in range
        For each c in rng.cells
            ' If value is greater then Z2 and respective column in row 153 = 0 and cell is not in 153 then change 153 = respective row column 1 
            If c.value > ELevel and .cells(153, c.column) = 0 and c.row <> 153 Then
                 .cells(153,c.column) = .cells(c.row, 1)
            ' If value is less then Z2 and cell is not in 153 then change 153 = 0
            elseif c.value < ELevel and c.row <> 153 then
                 .cells(153, c.column) = 0
            ' Clean up - if cell is in row 153 and value = 0 then change to "N/A"
            elseif c.row = 153 and c.value = 0 then
                c.value = "N/A"
            end if
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Please let me know if I've misunderstood

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. It only created one row (row 153) There should be a lot more

Comment: @Jack in what sort of structure?

Comment: Ok, so I think the main thing people are getting confused about is the z loop. It is essentially a loop that I manually change. First I run the code with the z loop from 1 to 0 and paste values in row 153, then I run code with z loop from 1 to 1 and paste results in 154. But with the code you wrote, I only see results in row 153. That means it only ran one case (one z loop)

Comment: @Jack ok so we're missing the manual Input that you add. So then from your layout your values in the 52+ rows would possibly overwrite the 153+ rows? And what should the z values (let's call them) actually equal

Comment: I think you need to read the original question asked by the OP (referenced in this question). You seem to have completely lost the original intent before we even get to the modification the OP wants. From [Using VBA to get a threshold value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922657/using-vba-to-get-a-threshold-value): "If B2>Z2 but also next 4 sequential cells (B3-B6)>Z2, then copy A2 to B153 and move to next column." Your code needs to see chunks of cells and not just one cell. Look at the code posted in this  question and my answer for the specific logic.

Comment: To answer your question about why use three loops (per my answer I agree), BUT none of your loops eliminations were beneficial. You turned a double loop through the cells into an iterator through the cells. Same number of inner loop iterations. I'd call that change a net loss due to the probable iterator overhead and the dependence on a desirable iterator order for efficent answering of the original question. The other loop you eliminated leaves your code not even performing the task of the original code (per my earlier comment).